# Clarification on exercise in C* Algebras By Murphy

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

I'm working through some exercises from Ch.2 of C* algebras By Murphy, and I'm stuck on the very first part of a problem.  The problem is the following:

Let $A$ be a unital $C^{*}$ algebra.  If $r(a) < 1$, and $b = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{{*n}} a^n \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, show that $b \geq I$, and that $||bab^{-1}|| < 1$.

So I don't really wan't help on the exercise, but I do want to understand how the setup of the problem even makes sense.

First off, what if $a=0$?  Then $r(a) = 0 < 1$, but then $b=0$, and hence $b \ngeq I$ and $b^{-1}$ doesn't exist, so the problem statement seems nonsensical.

Secondly, I don't see how $r(a) < 1$ garentees the existence of $b \in A$.  Since we're in a Banach space, it suffices to verify that $\left| \left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{*n}a^n \right| \right| < \infty$, and then invoke the existence of the square root of the element $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{*n}a^n$.  However, doing this I yield: $$\left| \left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{*n}a^n \right| \right| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ||a^{*n}a^n|| = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ||a^n||^2 \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ||a||^{2n}.$$  However, for the righthand sum to converge, I need that $||a|| <1$, and $r(a) < 1$ doesn't guarantee this, as $a$ isn't assumed normal (so that $||a|| = r(a)$).

Is tthe problem missing some assumptions that aren't stated, or am I missing something obvious?

Thank you.

Comment: The first term of the series describing $b$  i.e. $(a^*)^0a^0=e.$ That's why $b^2\ge I$ and $b\ge I.$

Comment: The series is convergent but you should use $\sum \|a^n\|^2.$ Apply the root test and make use of the formula for $r(a).$

Comment: Isn't also $\|a\| \leq r(a)$? I think you need normality only for the other inequality.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets The inequality $r(a)\le \|a\|$ is true in general. For normal elements the converse inequality  holds.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. I must have reversed it in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, $a^0=I$. So when $a=0$, $b=I$, and in general $b\geq I$.

As for your second questions, the key is that
$$
r(a)=\lim_n\|a^n\|^{1/n}=\lim_n\|a^{*n}a^n\|^{1/2n}.
$$
You should be able to conclude from this that $\|a^{*n}a^n\|<1$ for $n$ big enough.